# create_role not adding discord permissions

Tags: python, discord.py

**Command:**

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def pp2(ctx, *, arg):
client = bot
author = ctx.message.author
permissions = discord.Permissions(administrator=True)
await client.create_role(author.server, name="{}".format(arg), permissions=permissions, colour=discord.Colour(0xb400ff))
role = discord.utils.get(author.server.roles, name="{}".format(arg))
await client.add_roles(author, role)
```

**Problem:**

If I do `?pp2 ExampleName` it will create the role and add to the author that did the command, but doesn't add the Administrator permitions to the role. How can I fix that? It doesn't output any errors, not sure what to fix.

Comment: `create role` returns a `Role` object, so you can skip the `get` line by just doing `role = await client.creat_role(...`.  What permissions does your bot have?  It may not be able to create roles with higher permissions than it has.

Comment: it has everyrole